# JavaScript event listener quiz

Tags: javascript, event-handling, addeventlistener

I am fairly new to Javascript and up until this point, have mainly been working through codecademy.com's JavaScript course, which has been great but focuses just on writing JavaScript code and not on using it for web development purposes(i.e. tying it in with HTML and CSS).

I recently got a JavaScript course from Udemy.com which does focus on usuing JavaScript for web development, which has also been great so far but there are some minor things that the instructor does which I know are not considered best practices anymore(the course may be a bit dated).

The main one is he is using HTML event handler attributes as opposed to using event listeners.  I am trying to modify the code in the example to use an event listener, but so far I have had no success.  I was hoping someone might be able to give a struggling newbie some insight into what I am doing wrong.

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple JavaScript Quiz</title>
        <link rel ="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script type = "text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div id = "container">
            <header>
                <h1> Simple Javascript Quiz </h1>
                <p> Test your knowledge in <strong>JavaScript fundamentals.</strong> </p>
            </header>
            <section>
                <div id = "results"></div>
                <form name = "quizForm" id = "qForm">
                    <h3>1. In which HTML element do we put in JavaScript code?</h3>
                    <input type = "radio" name = "q1" value = "a" id = "q1a">a. &lt;js&gt;<br>
                    <input type = "radio" name = "q1" value = "b" id = "q1b">b. &lt;script&gt;<br>
                    <input type = "radio" name = "q1" value = "c" id = "q1c">c. &lt;body&gt;<br>
                    <input type = "radio" name = "q1" value = "c" id = "q1d">d. &lt;link&gt;<br>

                    <h3>2. Which HTML attribute is used to reference an external JavaScript file?</h3>
                    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="a" id="q2a">a. src<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="b" id="q2b">b. rel<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="c" id="q2c">c. type<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="d" id="q2d">d. href<br>

                    <h3>3. How would you write "Hello" in an alert box?</h3>
                    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="a" id="q3a">a. msg("Hello");<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="b" id="q3b">b. alertBox("Hello");<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="c" id="q3c">c. document.write("Hello");<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="d" id="q3d">d. alert("Hello");<br>

                    <h3>4. JavaScript is directly related to the "Java" programming language</h3>
                    <input type="radio" name="q4" value="a" id="q4a">a. True<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="q4" value="b" id="q4b">b. False<br>

                    <h3>5. A variable in JavaScript must start with which special character</h3>
                    <input type="radio" name="q5" value="a" id="q5a">a. @<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="q5" value="b" id="q5b">b. $<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="q5" value="c" id="q5c">c. #<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="q5" value="d" id="q5d">d. No Special Character<br>
                    <br><br>
                    <input type = "submit" value ="Submit Answers">
                </form> 
            </section>
            <footer>
                <p>Copyright &copy; 2014, All Rights Reserved</p>
            </footer>   
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript:

```
function submitAnswers() {
    var total = 5;
    var score = 0;

    //get user input
    var q1 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q1"].value;
    var q2 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q2"].value;
    var q3 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q3"].value;
    var q4 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q4"].value;
    var q5 = document.forms["quizForm"]["q5"].value;

    var qArray = [q1, q2, q3, q4, q5];

    //reminds user to select each button if left unselected
    for (var i = 0; i < qArray.length; i++) {
        if (qArray[i] === null || qArray[i] === "") {
            alert("You forgot to fill out question " + [i + 1]);
            return false;
        }
    }

    //set correct answers
    var answers =["b", "a", "d", "b", "d"];

    //check answers
    for (var i = 0; i < qArray.length; i++) {
        if (qArray[i] === answers[i]) {
            score++;
        }
    }   
    //display results
    var results = document.getElementById('results');
    results.innerHTML = '<h3>You scored <span>' + score + '</span> out of <span>' + total + '</span></h3>'; 
    return false;


};

var qForm = document.getElementById('qForm');
qForm.addEventListener('submit', submitAnswers, false);
```

The project is a simple HTML quiz that consists of 5 multiple choice questions.

When the submit button is clicked the code should calculate the score and write the result to an empty `<div>` element at the top of the page.  If any question is left with an unchecked radio button, an alert window should pop up letting the user know.

The code runs fine when I use the HTML event handler attribute, but when I remove the HTML event handler and use the event lister instead I can't seem to get the code to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific issue here is that your script is referenced in the head element so it starts executing before the DOM is built and your qForm variable is null.
You will want to move the script reference to the bottom of the file. You also should add an event as a parameter to your function and call event.preventDefault() early on, so that your form does not end up submitting inadvertently if the return false is not reached for some reason.
Finally, you are not reading the radio button checked status correctly, but since you are learning I would leave that for you to figure.

Comment: That did it!  Thanks for pointing out the radio button checked status error.  I'll check that out.  I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `addEventListener` prevent form submission with `preventDefault` method:

```
function submitAnswers(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // rest of the code ...
}
```

In your previous version when you used inline event registration `onsubmit="return submitAnswers()"` you could use simple `return false` to do the same.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7xggt9ky/

Comment: Ahhh, thanks so much!  I have spent all morning trying to figure this out.